# How can i install .net framework with specific language pack according to the language selected by user in language selection dialog?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

i am providing setup in multiple UI languages....
i want to install .net framework language pack according to language selection by user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution for the above question...

I created two features for my setup installation...
then i just associated my language pack prerequisite with one of the feature in conditional installation window...

then in the setup design tab, for the selected feature, i put the condition which i wanted to execute for execution of the featute...

i.e, ProductLanguage<>1031 then level=200

thus when i select german language then only language pack is installed, otherwise it will continue execution ur installation....